# Post Form Form Theme to Custom Controller in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

How to Post Form in View Folder of my Custom Theme .The Senerio is I want to Post my Custom Form data.the form is in footer view of my Custom Theme ..So i had to post the data to Controller then save it into db but my question is how to Post Form data form theme view to my controller .The Controller resides in my Custom Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orchard, there is a default route that uses the module name as the area.  So you should be able to post to your custom controller using a url like this: /ModuleName/ControllerName/Method

So without using the html form helpers, it would be something like this...

```
<form action='/ModuleName/ControllerName/Action' method='POST'>
  <input name="someValue" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Me Stands in theme i want to post data from theme view to my module cutom controller how can i do this if u can give me code related example then it will clear me more

Comment: I've added a simple html example.